# computed property "for get" and "for set"

Tags: swift, object, computed-properties

i want to manipulate a object without really  modify it, every time i try to modify it, i create a new "object modifier" and modify it, every time i try to read my object if there's a modifier i read it, if not a read the real object, i do it like this :

```
class realObj {

    var modifier: ObjModifier? = nil
    var realData:String = "Original Data"

    var data: String {
        get {
            if modifier != nil {
                return modifier.data
            }else{
                return realData
            }
        }
        set {
            if modifier != nil {
                modifier.data = newValue
            }else{
                modifier = ObjModifier(copiedFrom:self)
                modifier.data = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's work perfectly but, if my data is a other object it's not working because if i do for exemple  `object.data.name = "new name"` it's basically a `get` not a `set`so it's not create a "object modifier".

is it possible to fix that properly in swift, with something like `for get` and `for set` in my computed property or do i have to create 2 computed property one `dataForGet` and one `dataForSet` ?

Thanks you

EDIT :

classes :

```
class Person{
    
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    
    init(name:String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

class Cat{
    
    var nameReal:String
    var ownerReal:Person
    
    var name: String {
        get {
            return nameReal
        }
        set {
            nameReal = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var owner: Person {
        get {
            return ownerReal
        }
        set {
            ownerReal = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(name:String, owner:Person) {
        self.nameReal = name
        self.ownerReal = owner
    }
}

class CatModifier:Cat{
    
    init(copiedFrom:Cat) {
        super.init(name: copiedFrom.nameReal, owner: copiedFrom.ownerReal)
    }
}

class UnModifiableCat:Cat{
    
    var modifier:CatModifier? = nil
    
    override var name: String{
        get {
            if modifier != nil {
                return modifier!.name
            }
            else{
                return nameReal
            }
        }
        set {
            if modifier != nil {
                modifier!.name = newValue
            }
            else{
                modifier = CatModifier(copiedFrom:self)
                modifier!.name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var owner: Person {
        get {
            if modifier != nil {
                return modifier!.owner
            }
            else{
                return ownerReal
            }
        }
        set {
            if modifier != nil {
                modifier!.owner = newValue
            }
            else{
                modifier = CatModifier(copiedFrom:self)
                modifier!.owner = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Using :

```
func printInfo(cat:Cat) {
    print("Cat name: \(cat.name), Owner name: \(cat.owner.name), Owner age: \(cat.owner.age)")
    print("Cat name Real: \(cat.nameReal), Owner Real name: \(cat.ownerReal.name), Owner Real age: \(cat.ownerReal.age)")
    print("")
}

let unModifiableCat1 = UnModifiableCat(name: "Luna", owner: Person(name: "Nick", age: 23))

printInfo(cat: unModifiableCat1)
//Cat name: Luna, Owner name: Nick, Owner age: 23
//Cat name Real: Luna, Owner Real name: Nick, Owner Real age: 23

unModifiableCat1.name = "Modified Name"

printInfo(cat: unModifiableCat1)
//Cat name: Modified Name, Owner name: Nick, Owner age: 23
//Cat name Real: Luna, Owner Real name: Nick, Owner Real age: 23

//Work because i call the 'set' of my computed property 'name' so it create a modifier


let unModifiableCat2 = UnModifiableCat(name: "Luna", owner: Person(name: "Nick", age: 23))

printInfo(cat: unModifiableCat2)
//Cat name: Luna, Owner name: Nick, Owner age: 23
//Cat name Real: Luna, Owner Real name: Nick, Owner Real age: 23

unModifiableCat2.owner.name = "Modified Name"

printInfo(cat: unModifiableCat2)
//Cat name: Luna, Owner name: Modified Name, Owner age: 23
//Cat name Real: Luna, Owner Real name: Modified Name, Owner Real age: 23

//Dont work beacause i call the 'get' of my computed propery 'owner'
```

Comment: I find your code a bit strange (and not compiling) and the statement `object.data.name = "new name"` can not work since `data` is a String so overall it’s very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code to reproduce a problem?

Comment: the real code is very long so i added a simple exemple